# Who was Kylo Ren fighting against in order to acquire the first location cube?

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

In the initial fighting scene of *Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker*, Kylo Ren (with his own contingent of Stormtroopers) were fighting a group of people in order to acquire the first location cube that would lead him to Palpatine.

Who were those people he was fighting?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [movieweb](https://movieweb.com/the-rise-of-skywalker-opening-scene-explained-planet/):

> The Visual Dictionary. Author Pablo Hidalgo has given us some information as to why Kylo Ren is there in the first place. You can read an excerpt from the book below.
>
> > "Kylo soon outpaces his stormtrooper escorts as he cuts a swath of destruction through the Alazmec who attempt to block his path to Vader's castle - or rather, its crumbling ruins. Kylo enters the castle grounds with purpose, and finds an ark containing an artifact that will lead him to answers."
>
> As for who the Alazmec are, they're the unfortunate aliens who Kylo Ren is easily mowing down with his Lightsaber at the beginning of the movie. They're described as "cult colonists" who "voyage to Mustafar in pilgrimage seeking to tap into the powers that supposedly fueled him," and wear "sodium silicate-dusted protective clothing."